# execute passed function argument inside scala thread

Tags: java, scala

I simlpy want to execute a passed function to be executed in scala. Something like Functor in java world.

I javascript, I would do it as

```
function g(f, data) { 
     f() 
}

g(function(){ 
   console.log('I must be printed')
  }, 1000)
```

I tried the same in scala as below, (but with Java Thread), which wont work

```
object FunctionProgInHamiltonRoad {

  def g(f: (String) => Unit): String = {
    val task = new TimerTask {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        println("I'm printed in g inside thread hell")
        f
      }
    }
    new Thread(task).start()

    println("finishing off g")
    "printed in g"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      g((id : String) => {println("I must be printed in g.")})
  }
}
```

output

finishing off g
I'm printed in g inside thread hell

but the passed function is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
val task = new TimerTask {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    println("I'm printed in g inside thread hell")
    f("")
  }
}
```

if you want to execute function should like: `f()`,

but for `(id : String) => {println("I must be printed in g.")}` this function, it should need a parameter to exeucte, like: `f(parameter)`